# Amazon Product Advertising API search error - 'itemsearcherrorresponse' with no additional error information

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api, amazon-advertising-api

Suddenly, today, I could not continue to perform `ItemSearch` queries on the Amazon Product Advertising API.

This is the complete XML error response I get.

`<element '{http:="" ecs.amazonaws.com="" doc="" 2005-10-05="" }itemsearcherrorresponse'="" at="" 0x7f58cc173138=""></element>`

Error responses usually come with additional information in a `Code`
field, that helps understand the cause of the error. But not on this case.

Have I been blocked? or Does this mean the service is down momentarily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per I have understood, Amazon has suspended access to the Product Advertising API since the beginning of July.

You can ask for a restoration of your access, but owing to what I have been able to read on the web there are very few exceptions.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, would you mind letting me know the source of this information? I am trying to figure out if this is the reason why we can't manage Product Advertising API Keys anymore from our associate control panel. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @wiredmark, 

There was an announce by Amazon some months ago. I do not work for this project anymore, so unfortunateley I cannot retrieve the direct link. If you connect to https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/home, you should see something in the "Help" tab.